# IF condition doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, if-statement

Little problem with this php code:

```
$good = "<img src=./images/good.gif>";
$bad = "<img src=./images/bad.gif>";
while ($muuttuja <= $filecount) {
    $muuttuja = $muuttuja + 1;
    $arvostelutiedosto = "./moviefiles/$movie/review" . $muuttuja . ".txt";
    if (file_exists($arvostelutiedosto)) {
        $arvostelu = file($arvostelutiedosto);
        list($teksti[$muuttuja], $arvio[$muuttuja], $tekija[$muuttuja], $tyopaikka[$muuttuja]) = $arvostelu;
    }

        if ($arvio[$muuttuja] === "bad") {
            $arvio[$muuttuja] = $bad;
        } else {
            $arvio[$muuttuja] = $good;
        }

}

<?= $arvio[1] ?>
<?= $arvio[2] ?>
etc
```

I have files in that path, which is determined above. Second line on that file is "bad" or "good". I want to compare that with "bad" and print one specific image (which is determined by $bad and $good) if it is true and second one if it is false. Where do i have error (and by that i mean why it doesn't work)? Now it prints same image to every "review"

var_dump($arvio[$muuttuja]) gives output string(28)"image" <- image is real image, not text.

var_dump($arvostelu) gives output array(4) {[0]}=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(4) "bad" [2]=> string(7) "testing" [3]=> string(1) "a"}

string 1 is same as in if ($arvio[$muuttuja] === "bad")

Comment: What do you mean `Where do i have error? `. If there is any error, PHP shows the error in browser or php_error_log. You need to check and post what kind of error are you facing it. By the way, where did you declare `$bad` and `$good` variables?

Comment: $good = "<img src=./images/good.gif>"; 
   $bad = "<img src=./images/bad.gif>"; Are determined above that code. I will edit question. And with error i mean why it doesn't work.

Comment: edit your post with the output of var_dump($arvio[$muuttuja]);

Comment: Added output to original post

Comment: I think that your error come from above in your code

Comment: Now i got string(28)"image"

Comment: edit your post with the output of var_dump($arvostelu);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

```
var_dump($arvostelu) gives output array(4) {[0]}=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(4) "bad" [2]=> string(7) "testing" [3]=> string(1) "a"}

string 1 is same as in if ($arvio[$muuttuja] === "bad")
```

but is not real, look at:

```
[1]=> string(4) "bad"
```

bad have 3 characters not 4, try with:

```
if(trim($arvio[$muuttuja]) == 'bad')
```

Comment: Thank you, awesome helping :)  Should trim be used almost always on comparing strings?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure entirely where the problem lies, but you might try this instead of the if then else?

```
$arvio[$muuttuja] = ( strtolower(  trim( $arvio[$muuttuja] ) ) )==='bad' ? $bad : $good;
```

and perhaps after checking that the file exists you ought to use:-

```
clearstatcache()
```